# Symfony validate request

Tags: php, symfony

У меня есть роут, который получает данные из одной из форм по ajax и дальше эти данные идут на другой сервер. Но я не могу понять, как можно валидировать пришедшие данные? Когда пользовалеся laravel, то это делалось довольно просто

```
public function bookNewPerson()
    {
        $attributes = request()->validate(
            [
                'dateTime' => 'required',
                'lastName' => 'required|string|between:3,15',
                'phoneNumber' => 'required|string|between:13,13',
            ]
        );
        // ...
    }
```

Как я могу валидировать входящий запрос? Entity для этих данных у меня нет, т.к. я не планирую с ними работать, в БД они не хранятся. Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

1) Для валидации не имеет значение значение, Entity это или нет. Для Валидатора это просто класс с аннотациями.Создаете класс, в котором ваши данные из request. Прописываете в нем правила валидации через анотации и валидируете. https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

2) Можно так же создавать правила без аннотаций и дополнительного класса: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html

Чтобы не дублировать код, вот есть ответ с примерами: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737796/validation-for-rest-api-in-symfony-4

Answer (score 2):

В симфони можно по разному валидировать, но Вы пишите, что у вас есть некая форма, можете подробней прочитать в документации [валидация формы](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#validating-forms)

Создаёте php-класс формы. Если она не привязана к сущности то указываете `'data_class' => null`.

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ]);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }

}
```

А в контроллере создаёте экземпляр формы и делаете валидацию

```
class YourController extends AbstractController
{


    /**
     * @Route("/search", name="search")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, null, [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'action' => '',
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            $errors = $form->getErrors(true);
            // ...
        }

        // ...

    }


}
```

ps. [Отобразить](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-forms) поля формы также можно достаточно просто указав в шаблоне:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Есть Бандлы похожие на Laravel:**

1. Компонент проверки запросов для Symfony. Упрощает проверку свойств запроса (объекта Request) без необходимости использования формы Symfony:
   [symfony-request-validation](https://github.com/123inkt/symfony-request-validation)
2. Описание валидации запроса (объекта Request) через нотации:
   [RequestValidatorBundle](https://github.com/seferov/RequestValidatorBundle)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)